# Как отследить изменение DisplayIndex DataGridView у Column C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Мне нужно отследить, что пользователь менял столбцы местами, но такого события я не обнаружил. Подскажите как это можно реализовать

Answer (score 1):

```
private void DataGridView1_ColumnDisplayIndexChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
{
}
```

e - твой столбец, который ты передвигаешь, индекс и наименование

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: @РосикПоль, если помогло, то поставь, как лучший ответ)
Спасибо.